# Connect Excel to Access Form via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I wanted to connect my Excel to my Access DB.
I want to extract Data from a Form into Excel.

```
 Sub GetDataFromDB()
    
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim DBPATH, PRVD, connString, query As String
    
    DBPATH = "...."
    PRVD = "Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;"
    
    connString = "Provider=" & PRVD & "Data Source=" & DBPATH
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open connString
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm Forms![frm_name], acFormDS, "", "", , acNormal
    (Do Something)
End Sub
```

Now I get an error 424 that an Object is needed but I don't know to to get access to that specific Form in my DB.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I assume that is code you want to use in Excel. In that case you can't open an Access form within Excel with `DoCmd.OpenForm`.

Comment: Yes, you must use automation to first _open_ Access, then open the form.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally you get your data form a table or a query. May be you should
> explain better what you want to accomplish. Getting data directly from
> a form doesn't sound logical. If you want to open an access form try;
>
> Ps, Dim declarations are not correct, Dim x as string, y as string
> otherwise they will be variant.

```
Public Sub Displayform(conPath As String)

   Dim objAccess As Access.Application
         'Check that this is the path on YOUR PC for
         'Northwind.mdb, which ships with Access.
         'Const conPATH = "C:\Users\Myname\documents\PrintMe.accdb"
         'Create an instance of the Access application object.
    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
          'Access and display the application window.
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase conPath
    objAccess.Visible = True

        'Open the Employees form.
         'objAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm "Cust List"
         ' Maximize other Access window and quit current application.

    objAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMaximize
    Application.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdAppMinimize

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me. One more question:
How can I access a certain variable/element in my form?

Normally in my Access DB its: 
Forms![frm_custom]![sJahr] = jahr